# Calculating Distributions that Have Dependencies

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

I want to calculate a distribution from a function that depends on several variables, where there is an interdependency between the variables. This works:

```
TransformedDistribution[(a - b)* c, 
 {a \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[20, 5], 
  b \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[30, 2], 
  c \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[100, 8]}]

RandomVariate[%]
(* -442.531 *)
```

Since there are no interdependencies. This, however, does not:

```
TransformedDistribution[(a - b)* c,
 {a \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[20, 5], 
  b \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[a, 2], 
  c \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[100, 8]}]

RandomVariate[%]
```

> During evaluation of In[175]:= NormalDistribution::realprm: Parameter [FormalX]1 at position 1 in NormalDistribution[[FormalX]1,2] is expected to be real.

I found that `ParameterMixtureDistribution` works for this:

```
ParameterMixtureDistribution[
 TransformedDistribution[(a - b)*c,
  {b \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0.75*a, (0.5 a - 1)/6], 
   c \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[100, 8]}], 
   a \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[20, 5]]

RandomVariate[%] 
(* 741.52 *)
```

But, not for this:

```
ParameterMixtureDistribution[
 TransformedDistribution[(a - b)*Log[c],
  {b \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0.75*a, (0.5 a - 1)/6], 
   c \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[100, 8]}], 
   a \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[20, 5]]

RandomVariate[%]
```

I don't get an error...but I'm not getting useful output: it just returns the input.

Comment: I think my question may not have been well formulated. What's the etiquette? Should I delete the question altogether and ask a new questions? Severely edit it?

Answer (score 4):

Well, you have some fundamental problems with the model specification even when you are able to obtain a result:  your standard deviation is negative if $a < 2$, which occurs with approximate probability $0.000159109$.  That may seem negligible but it is once in approximately every $6285$ simulations.

In order to address this you would need to adjust your definitions; e.g., left-truncate $a$.  A similar but less egregious problem happens if you attempt to compute $\log c$:  this will not be real-valued with probability $3.73256 \times 10^{-36}$ which is computationally negligible.  In any case, even if $c < 0$, *Mathematica* would simply compute a complex-valued logarithm for the realization.  But it will refuse to generate a random variate from a normal distribution with negative or zero standard deviation.

As a result, for your specific inputs, I would not trust the output of `RandomVariate` even when it does give you one.  If your intent is to generate random variates from such a model, you are better off doing it manually; i.e., generate a variate for $a$, then use this to generate $b$ (where truncation could be implemented by discarding any realizations where $a \le 2$); then generate $c$, and finally compute whatever function of $a, b, c$ is desired.  It is also likely to be faster.

---

Running the following code on a 3-year old laptop takes about 7 seconds and generates nearly $10^7$ variates, a full order of magnitude more than the number you attempted to generate.

```
Select[ParallelTable[If[# > 2, (# - RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[.75 #, (.5 # - 1)/6]]) RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[100, 8]]] &[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[20, 5]]], 10^7], NumberQ]
```

Meanwhile, my attempt to use your code with `ParameterMixtureDistribution` is so slow, it takes 16 seconds to just get $10^4$ variates.  I don't claim that my code is optimized; in fact, I think there are many other people here who could do it better and faster than this.  Since I don't know what code you used for your manual attempt I can't say why your implementation was slow.

If you are needing to combine this with other distributions, you should have included this in the scope of your original question, rather than asking about one part that might not fully capture the issue you are facing.  But as I have already stated, you have more fundamental problems with your model specification.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I hope you'll forgive me that I tried to reduce my problem to the essential problem I was having to keep things simpler, but I think I didn't do that well. I have been using TruncatedDistribution[] and other means to prevent issues as you described, but left them out to simplify the code here.

Comment: I also tried doing it "manually," but found this was actually very, very slow. I created a Module[], and generated RandomVariates for a, b, and c, in sequence, then calculated (a-b)*Log(c). Finally, I wrapped that in Table[] to generate a list of results. 1,000,000 iterations takes > 260 seconds. Since I want to convert this to a distribution (with EmpiricalDistribution[]?) to combine with still more distributions, the time is prohibitive. Is there a faster way?

Comment: @Brian See my edits above.

Answer (score 4):

This is an extended comment echoing the good advice from @heropup.  While `ParameterMixtureDistribution` function is very handy, your second example doesn't need it.  Writing things out in terms of the random variables we have

$$A\sim N(20,5)$$
$$C\sim N(100,8)$$
$$Z\sim N(0,2)$$
$$B=A+Z$$

So

$$(A-B)C=(A-(A+Z))C=Z C$$

And you can get the desired result with

```
TransformedDistribution[z * c,
 {z \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, 2], 
  c \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[100, 8]}]
```

For your second example suppose you fix the issue that @heropup pointed out with making the standard deviation always non-negative with `Abs[a/2 - 1]/6` and changing $\log C$ to $\log{|C|}$ (as I don't thing you want to deal with complex numbers - at least I assume you don't):

Then

```
$$B = 3A/4 + Z |A/2 - 1|/6$$
```

The *Mathematica* code becomes

```
dist = TransformedDistribution[(aa - 3 aa/4 - zz Abs[aa/2 - 1]/6) Log[Abs[cc]],
  {aa \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[20, 5], 
   cc \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[100, 8], 
   zz \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, 1]}]
SeedRandom[12345];
RandomVariate[dist]
(* 25.4829 *)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As I mentioned in my comment to @heropup, I think my question has been too watered down. In your answer, you took advantage of the fact that a Normal distribution simply has its mean shifted when adding a value to it. Clever! My intent, however, was to understand how to generate a distribution that depends on the output of another distribution. What if, for example, the mean _and standard deviation_ of b depended on a? Or if b were a Transformed distribution, with a transformation that used the output of a?

Comment: "It depends."  It depends on the specifics of the example.  Some scenarios have nice results for the moments but not for the resulting pdf.  Also, there are "You can't get there from here" issues.  An example is that `ParameterMixtureDistribution` gives you the marginal distribution for $B$.  But you need the joint distribution of $B$ and $A$ in your examples.  In short, you'll need to give relatively specific examples.  If you edit your question, I'm happy to delete my "extended comment."  I don't know the recommended etiquette.

Comment: "My intent, however, was to understand how to generate a distribution that depends on the output of another distribution."  Understood.  There are statistical theory approaches and what *Mathematica* has currently implemented in nice compact functions and other more basic *Mathematica* functions that require more thought.